# Trying to improve and expand "professional" solar installation

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, solar-panels, solar

Several years ago I contracted a local firm to install 56 solar panels on my roof. I know they used a licensed electrician and the utility company approved and installed my Net Meter but the system was never inspected and I have subsequently realized several issues I am not pleased with: 1) there is no external disconnect, 2) the solar input to my load center exceeds the 120% for the bus capacity.

I want to add 22 additional panels and correct my concerns. My house is supplied by two side-by-side 200amp load centers. They are old Square D panels and I am having trouble finding the exact specs on those panels but similar panels from that time period appear to have 225amp maximum bus capacity. They are series L7 QOC 30MW225

[image]
[image]
[image]

It is my understanding I should be able to bring ((120% x 225 amps - 200) x 80%) = 56amps to each load center. I will have 6 total strings of solar panels (three strings to each load center) with 13 (or less) panels on each string using Enphase IQ7+ microinverters. The panels are roughly 300W each for a maximum of 16.25amps per string or 48.75amps to each load center.

The diagram below is the current configuration:
[image]

This is the diagram of my proposed changes:
[image]

Does my proposed plan seem to be appropriate +/- a few amps?

I had contacted the Utility about doing a supply side tap (which would eliminate the bus capacity issue) but my system is grandfathered in for full kWh credit on power I put out on the grid; the laws have changed since and they said ANY change I make to the system would knock me into the less credit/kWh group.

Comment: Who is your electric utility?  Also, can you get us photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel cabinets for your existing electrical panels please? (SqD unfortunately doesn't leave that stuff out on the inside of the door for folks to easily see)

Comment: This sounds like "*any change*" for a company that **can pay you less** if you make *any change* - might not be a terribly smart move. Might sort your perceived issues, but it also might cost you a fair amount of money into the far future if you get full-priced credit for overproduction as of now.

Comment: I'm betting, and this may ultimately be a bad bet, that I can make these changes without the utility company knowing. Kentucky Utilities.

Comment: The key as to whether you could this without the utility knowing (or more likely, *caring enough to investigate*) is what your original contract says about how much power you can push out to the grid. If your contract says 70A (your nominal max based on the numbers you provided) or 75A (a modest buffer) then on sunny days where you're not home and have everything off and start pushing out 90A, they will eventually catch on and you'll have a problem. If the contract says 100A then you'll be fine.

Comment: They will surely notice added production, so "array 5&6^ are just waving a red flag at them. The other changes might be ignored, but that one is going to show up flashing in bright neon. Adding even one panel will be noticeable, adding 22 will have them coming for a visit to cut your rate (they have that incentive to notice changes.) They know, in more detail than you might think, how much power you put out now, so if that increases they'll know something has changed.

Comment: @drjrt -- there should be a label on one side of the cabinet's interior that has more information on it

Comment: I found the info inside the panel; never noticed that before. The panels are going on a flat porch roof. The utility company would need a ladder or drone (and the interest) to see the new panels. On the other hand I never thought about them "noticing" the increased system production. I am not aware of a contract with KU regarding any specific maximum system output but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Wonder how I can find that out without raising a red flag?

Comment: @drjrt look at your copy of the contract. You should have copies of anything you've signed.

Comment: They certainly don't need to visually see the added panels. They'll see them just fine via the meter without physically taking a look.

Comment: Well, learning something new everyday. Finally tracked down my paperwork with KU (the installer had it and never gave it to me) and I am listed at 15.1kW. So, if 50 of my panels are maxing out at 300W and I'm not consuming anything I will exceed this parameter. Adding 22 panels on a sunny day in the spring or fall I could easily exceed this value, potentially triggering an investigation? Given the political climate in KY regarding solar, I can't take the risk of losing full credit. Darn.